# Parameters in Aliases

Tags: linux, sh, alias

I've created this sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -name "$1" | xargs grep "$2"
```

and I've created an alias with the path of this script:

```
alias  FIND_FILE                    '/home/mypath/scriptpath/find.sh'
```

But, when I call my alias, the search doesn't give me a results. Why?

Comment: Make your script a function and alias the function - or make sure your script is executable with `chmod 0755 /home/mypath/scriptpath/find.sh`

Comment: Just for debugging, try to print the values of `$#`, `$1` and `$2`.